# Ruby Syntax (Blather)

Tags: ruby, syntax, xmpp

```
message :chat?, :body => 'pong' do |m|
   puts "ping!"
   say m.from, 'ping'
 end
```

In this code, what is `message` and what is `:chat?, :body` accessing?

Comment: In ruby, something starting with a `:` is a symbol, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561285/ruby-and-symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As bjhaid says, `message` is a method.

This method takes two arguments. Arguments can be surrounded by parentheses but the parentheses are optional. Arguments are separated by commas.

The first argument is a symbol `:chat?` ... symbols are not variables and don't represent anything except themselves.  We can assume that message looks at the first argument and if it's `:chat?` it will then execute some code conditionally.

The second argument is a hash... a hash is a collection of key/value pairs and it's usually surrounded by curly brackets. With the optional parentheses and curly brackets added the call looks like this...

```
message(:chat?, {:body => 'pong'}) do |m|
```

However, Ruby is smart enough to recognise an argument is a hash without needing the curly brackets. In the example you provided, the hash has one entry, the key is the symbol `:body` and the value is the string `'pong'`.

Finally we have the `do` `end` block... which is literally some lines of code that the method can choose to execute within itself.  The method (internally) might pass an argument to the block, and that's what the `|m|` is for... it defines what variables in the block are actually values passed into the block by the method when it chooses to 'yield' to (execute) the block.

Hope this clarifies how to parse that line.

EDIT

Just to clarify, in bjhaid's answer he shows the method as receiving three parameters, not two, because he chose to convert the block into a proc which is what the ampersand '&' before the last parameter indicates. Blocks and procs are similar but procs can be passed around like any other object, but blocks cannot be.  He could have also left it as two parameters and left the block as a block... it can still be executed from within the method.

Comment: That explained things perfectly. Thank You!

Comment: I'm glad I could help!  If you accept my answer (give it a green check) then I get more reputation, which is good for me and I'd be grateful.  With a good enough reputation, I can eventually become Secretary General of the United Nations. Ban Ki-moon has a phenomenal stackoverflow profile. :)

Answer (score 1):

`message` is a method that takes 3 arguments, a `Symbol`, a `Hash` and a `block`/`proc` object

so you could have defined `message` as below:

```
def message(sym, options, &block)
  #body of message
end
```